# ASP.NET CORE валидация Double, Decemal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, валидация, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-validation

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, валидация на стороне сервере (modelState) и на стороне клиента (плагин jquery.validator) не пропускает разделитtль "," . С чем связана данная проблема и как ее решить?[image]

Comment: Скорее всего, что валидаторы ожидают `.` вместо `,`

Comment: @ДанилСкрипник да, все верно. Но в базу необходимо вносить с ",". Если я введу с точкой, база не наполняется. Мне кажется не логично, с помощью регулярки менять точку на запятую, тем более у меня много моделей и много значений, если еще с валидацией на стороне клиента можно придумать что-то, то что делать на сервере я ума не приложу.

Comment: [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1). См. в самом конце примечание (Note), как раз по вашей теме: [GitHub issue 4076](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо огромное, это помогло.Опубликуйте как ответ, я приму его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Смотрите в самом конце примечание (Note), как раз по вашей теме: [GitHub issue 4076](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420).